# Format Excel while exporting through SSRS

Tags: excel, pdf, reporting-services

Hi I'm working with SSRS reports. 
While exporting the results to excel, results are starting from first column it self. But I want to provide some space for that. (i.e. insteated of starting from 1st column can we start it from 3rd or 4th column ? So that we can have some space)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to distribute the Excel version via a subscription and want a separate view on the report Report Manager, then you can create a parameter for the report like Hide_Columns and make the visibility of the column be dependent upon the value of the parameter.  If you want the user to run the report in the HTML view and want the extra columns to show up in Excel, then you are out of luck.